# Can Azure Service Bus offer Message Journaling?

Tags: azure, servicebus, azureservicebus

Can Azure Service Bus be set up to journal successfully received messages, like MSMQ can? If so, how?

Answer (score 1):

While Azure Service Bus does not explicitly have a Journal sub-queue, this scenario is easily achievable by using a Topic and 2 Subscriptions. Service Bus support publish-subscribe patterns so you can create a Topic and have the same send APIs/semantics as a Queue and then create 2 subscriptions say called "Destination" and "Journal". By default Subscriptions have a TRUE filter so receive all messages sent to a Topic, and you can receive from these subscriptions just as you would from a Queue.

More details are available here: 
http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-bus-dotnet-how-to-use-topics-subscriptions/

Comment: Thanks but unless I am misunderstanding something the scenario is different. As far as I know the Journal in MQ only logs successfully 'ack'd messages.

Comment: I suppose if I think about it some sort of client side tracing is basically the equivalent, as explicit logging of processed messages to a queue should really by application logic...